# Number edges of 3-regular graph so that every vertex has a 0,1, and 2 edge

Tags: graph-theory

Let's say you have a graph such that every vertex has exactly 3 edges. You try to number every edge of the graph with either a 0, 1, or 2 so that every vertex has exactly one of each type of edge. Is this always possible to do?

Comment: What do you know about edge coloring? A restatement of your problem asks if there is a $3$-regular graph that requires $4$ colors to edge color.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are asking if every $3$-regular graph is [3-edge-colorable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring). The answer is no, and (connected, bridgeless) counterexamples are called [snarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_%28graph_theory%29). (See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Snark.html) for more examples).

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.